# .NET Core MVC get route matched for logging middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my project I am logging every request using logging middleware. How can I get the route that was matched for the request for logging purposes?

I have the full path in the request e.g. /v1/User/123

But I want to log this: /v1/User/{id}

Here is what I have so far:

```
public async override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var path = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;

    await next();
}
```

This is in my base controller, how do I get this to the logging middleware?

Here is how I got it to the logging middleware:

BaseController:

```
public async override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var actionPath = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;

    HttpContext.Items.Add("ActionInfo", actionPath);

    await next();
}
```

LoggingMiddleware:

```
var actionInfo = context.Items["ActionInfo"];

if (actionInfo != null)
{
    actionMatched = actionInfo.ToString();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Also this only works if you are using attribute routing. How can this work if you are registering routes on startup?

Answer (score 3):

Well, plain and simple, you can't.

A route is an ASP.NET Core MVC concept and its existence can therefore only be found within the MVC middleware of ASP.NET Core. This is why you can access it from an ActionFilter, that's an ASP.NET Core MVC concept as well. From a piece of middleware, the closest you can get is by going to `httpContext.Request` and using `Path`/`Query`/`QueryString`/`Method`.

Knowing this, the choices you then have:

1. Implement your logger as an action filter. This allows you to easily access the route and other detailed bits of information like the controller and action method. But, requests that are handled outside of the MVC middleware (static file, authorization fails, name it) will not be logged.
2. Implement it as middleware and simply log the URL.
3. Store the data somehow, somewhere so that your middleware can access it, as you've done by adding items to the `HttpContext`. This feels quite hacky.

Option 1 and 2 are both fine choices and it depends on your needs which is best for you. Perhaps even both 1 and 2.